# Smarty accessing array

Tags: smarty

```
{foreach from=$ncache.recmd name=spon key=k item=v}
      {if ($smarty.foreach.spon.iteration%2) eq 0 || $smarty.foreach.spon.last}  
       <tr>
          <td>
             <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="iid[]" value="{$ncache.recmd[$k].item_id}"class="checkbox"/{$ncache.recmd[$k].model}{$ncache.recmd[$k].manufacturer}
             </label>
           </td>
           <td>
            <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="iid[]" value="{$ncache.recmd[($k+1)].item_id}" class="checkbox"/>{$ncache.recmd[($k+1)].model}{$ncache.recmd[($k+1)].manufacturer}
            </label>
           </td>
       </tr>
     {/if}
     {/foreach}
```

here is my smarty codes.

```
{$ncache.recmd[($k+1)].item_id}
{$ncache.recmd[$k+1].item_id}
{$ncache.recmd[$k++].item_id}
```

i tried to access to value
but result is invalid
i tried several form as above. but it still got problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but I think I see what you are trying to do. I don't know what version of Smarty you're using, but I had similar difficulty with Smarty v2. I found that $smarty.foreach..iteration was going to be the next index (1-based indexing instead of 0-based). In that case, try this:

```
{foreach from=$ncache.recmd name=spon key=k item=v}
{if ($smarty.foreach.spon.index % 2) eq 0 || $smarty.foreach.spon.last}
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="iid[]" value="{$ncache.recmd[$k].item_id}"class="checkbox"/{$ncache.recmd[$k].model}{$ncache.recmd[$k].manufacturer}
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="iid[]" value="{$ncache.recmd[$smarty.foreach.spon.iteration].item_id}" class="checkbox"/>{$ncache.recmd[$smarty.foreach.spon.iteration].model}{$ncache.recmd[$smarty.foreach.spon.iteration].manufacturer}
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
{/if}
{/foreach}
```